# How can I run 3 QProcess in background using the same executable

Tags: c++, qt, multiprocessing

I have a program that has a `Worker` class and this class has 3 `QProcess`es.

Each process will require a `QDate` as an argument.
I want to run all of them in background.

**The Problem**

If I try to specify more than 3 dates (meaning all processes are running),
the entire program freezes.

I've already tried using `QProcess::startDetached` but it pops up command prompts which I don't like.

I want everything to run in background, 3 processes running simultaneously.

Here's my code:

in **`worker.h`**

```
#ifndef WORKER_H
#define WORKER_H

#include <QObject>

#include <QDate>
#include <QProcess>
#include <QQueue>

class Worker: public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

signals:
    void processed(QString& date);
    void error(QString& error);
    void done(QString& done);

public:
    Worker();

    void run(QDate& start, QDate& end, int delay);

private slots:

    void onFinished1(int exitCode, QProcess::ExitStatus exitStatus);
    void onError1(QProcess::ProcessError);

    void onFinished2(int exitCode, QProcess::ExitStatus exitStatus);
    void onError2(QProcess::ProcessError);

    void onFinished3(int exitCode, QProcess::ExitStatus exitStatus);
    void onError3(QProcess::ProcessError);

private:
    QProcess* worker1;
    QProcess* worker2;
    QProcess* worker3;

    QQueue<QDate> date_list;
    int running;
};

#endif // WORKER_H
```

in **`worker.cpp`**

```
#include "worker.h"

#include <QDebug>
#include <QStringList>

Worker::Worker()
{
    worker1 = new QProcess(this);
    worker2 = new QProcess(this);
    worker3 = new QProcess(this);

    connect(worker1, SIGNAL(finished(int,QProcess::ExitStatus)),
            this, SLOT(onFinished1(int,QProcess::ExitStatus)));
    connect(worker1, SIGNAL(error(QProcess::ProcessError)),
            this, SLOT(onError1(QProcess::ProcessError)));

    connect(worker2, SIGNAL(finished(int,QProcess::ExitStatus)),
            this, SLOT(onFinished2(int,QProcess::ExitStatus)));
    connect(worker2, SIGNAL(error(QProcess::ProcessError)),
            this, SLOT(onError2(QProcess::ProcessError)));

    connect(worker3, SIGNAL(finished(int,QProcess::ExitStatus)),
            this, SLOT(onFinished3(int,QProcess::ExitStatus)));
    connect(worker3, SIGNAL(error(QProcess::ProcessError)),
            this, SLOT(onError3(QProcess::ProcessError)));

    running = 0;
}

void
Worker::onFinished1(int exitCode, QProcess::ExitStatus exitStatus)
{
    qDebug() << "worker 1: "
             << "Exit Code: " << exitCode
             << "Exit Status: " << exitStatus;

    running -= 1;
    if (date_list.empty() && running == 0) {
        //system("rm output.xlsx");
        system("copy .\\extractor\\output.xlsx output.xlsx");
        emit done(QString("Done generating output.xlsx"));
    }
}

void
Worker::onFinished2(int exitCode, QProcess::ExitStatus exitStatus)
{
    qDebug() << "worker 2: "
             << "Exit Code: " << exitCode
             << "Exit Status: " << exitStatus;

    running -= 1;
    if (date_list.empty() && running == 0) {
        //system("rm output.xlsx");
        system("copy .\\extractor\\output.xlsx output.xlsx");
        emit done(QString("Done generating output.xlsx"));
    }
}

void
Worker::onFinished3(int exitCode, QProcess::ExitStatus exitStatus)
{
    qDebug() << "worker 3: "
             << "Exit Code: " << exitCode
             << "Exit Status: " << exitStatus;

    running -= 1;
    if (date_list.empty() && running == 0) {
        //system("rm output.xlsx");
        system("copy .\\extractor\\output.xlsx output.xlsx");
        emit done(QString("Done generating output.xlsx"));
    }
}

void
Worker::onError1(QProcess::ProcessError /* error */)
{
    qDebug() << "worker 1: "
             << "Error: " << worker1->errorString();

    running -= 1;
    emit error(worker1->errorString());
}

void
Worker::onError2(QProcess::ProcessError /* error */)
{
    qDebug() << "worker 2: "
             << "Error: " << worker2->errorString();

    running -= 1;
    emit error(worker2->errorString());
}

void
Worker::onError3(QProcess::ProcessError /* error */)
{
    qDebug() << "worker 3: "
             << "Error: " << worker3->errorString();

    running -= 1;
    emit error(worker3->errorString());
}

void
Worker::run(QDate& start, QDate& end, int delay)
{
    qDebug() << __FUNCTION__
             << start
             << end
             << delay;

    while(start <= end) {
        date_list.push_back(start);
        start = start.addDays(1);
    }

    QProcess * current;
    QDate processed_date;
    QStringList args;

    qDebug() << date_list;

    while(! date_list.empty()) {
        bool has_available = false;
        if (worker1->state() != QProcess::Running) {
            current = worker1;
            processed_date = date_list.dequeue();
            has_available = true;
        } else if (worker2->state() != QProcess::Running) {
            current = worker2;
            processed_date = date_list.dequeue();
            has_available = true;
        } else if (worker3->state() != QProcess::Running) {
            current = worker3;
            processed_date = date_list.dequeue();
            has_available = true;
        }

        // Has available worker, start worker
        if (has_available) {
            running += 1;

            QString sdate = processed_date.toString("yyyy-MM-dd");
            args << sdate << QString::number(delay);
            current->start(".\\release\\extractor\\content.exe", args);
            args.clear();
            emit processed(sdate);
        }
        qDebug() << "running: " << running;
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you show the class definition for `Worker`.  Why create the processes and then wait for dates to become available before starting them rather than simply creating the processes as and when the dates become available?  In short, your program logic looks far more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: Hi @G.M., I've shared the entire code. Please check. The entire logic is the main process provides the worker processes with dates to be processed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program freezes because it is busy all the time with waiting on `QProcess` to be finished, i.e. `while(1)`. So, you do not return to the main event loop before all your dates are processed. If you wait long enough, your program will unfreeze.

Different solutions exist:

- Use the `finished` event to start processing a new date (until the list is empty), i.e. remove the infinite/waiting loop `while(1)`.
- Perform `Worker::run` in a separate thread.
- Call [`QCoreApplication::processEvents`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#processEvents-1) to process the pending events, for example when `has_available` is false.

*Note that I prefer the first solution as Qt is an event driven system.*

Comment: Hi, I already used Signals and Slots to notify the main process when dates have been processed already. I have shared the entire code to make it clearer.

Comment: I don't see why I should change my answer. Are you running in a separate thread? Also note that we like a minimal example rather than your original code, see [mcve]

Comment: Hi, the worker is not yet inheriting QThread. All your options seems to be in line with the Worker design pattern. I will check this.

P.S I understand the MCV, someone is just asking the class and the logic. Perhaps it was better to show him also the entire code.

Comment: @codekaizer Think about what happens once your `while` loop has consumed the first three dates from the queue.  It will set in a busy waiting loop until one of the processes is no longer in the `QProcess::Running` state.  I suspect what you're really wanting is a thread pool with three threads.  Each thread accepts one date at a time, then starts an appropriate `QProcess` and waits for it to complete.

Comment: @G.M. I think a thread pool with one tread for each parallel `QProcess` is somewhat overkill to just startup the asynchronous `QProcess`es. Using one thread is in my opinion the absolute maximum that is needed.

Comment: True enough.  That's what I get for typing before thinking :-)